# Filtro de busca que não filtra

Tags: php, html, mysql

Então, tenho uma página com um formulário de busca pro usuário selecionar o que vai aparecer na tabela dele.
Quando o usuário clicar no botão submit, deveria aparecer outra página com a tabela devidamente filtrada.

Esse é o código da página que vai abrir:

```
<!-- - - - - - Isso aqui é o filtro - - - - - - - - - -->
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error()) or die ('Nao foi possível conectar ao MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));
    mysqli_select_db($lnk,'db_banco') or die ('Nao foi possível ao banco de dados selecionado no MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM teste ORDER BY servico, estado, cidade ASC';
    $servico = $_POST['servico'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];

    if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico)) 
        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE servico LIKE '%".$servico."%' ORDER BY servico ASC";
    //echo($sqli);
    $qry = mysqli_query($lnk, $sqli) or die(mysqli_error($lnk));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado
    //$fields[] = array();
    if($num_fields > 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
            $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
        }
    }
    if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico)) {
        if($count > 0) {
            echo 'Encontrado registros com o nome: ' . $servico;
        } else {
            echo 'Nenhum registro foi encontrado com o nome: ' . $servico;
        }
    }
?>
<!-- - - - - - Tabela com as buscas- - - - - - -->
<table class="table table-bordered"> <tr>
<tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Serviço</th>
    <th class="no-responsive">Cidade</th>
    <th>Visualizar</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_serv)) {
    ?>
        <td><?=$row['nome'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['servico'];?></td>
        <td class="no-responsive"><?=$row['cidade'];?></td>
        <td><a href="visualiza.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Visualizar</a></td>
</tr>
        <?php    }?>
</table>

<?php

$table .= '<tbody>';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }
}
?>
<!-- - - - -  Isso aqui é a paginação - - - - - - - - -->
<?php
    $pagina_anterior = $pagina - 1;
    $pagina_posterior = $pagina + 1;
?>
<nav class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li>
            <?php
            if($pagina_anterior != 0){ ?>
                <a href="teste-busca.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_anterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <?php }  ?>
        </li>
        <?php 
        //Apresentar a paginacao
        for($i = 1; $i < $num_pagina + 1; $i++){ ?>
            <li><a href="teste-busca.php?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <li>
            <?php
            if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina){ ?>
                <a href="teste-busca.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_posterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <?php }  ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

> Obs: Percebi que tinha duas variáveis $sql recebendo consultas
>   diferentes, então mantive a primeria e mudei a última para sqli.
>   Depois disso a página aparece em branco a tabela nem chega a aparecer
>   na tela.

Comment: Eu recomendaria você remover todos os `@` que colocou no código para suprir mensagens de erro e faria um `var_dump($sql)` para verificar qual foi a instrução SQL executada.

Comment: Chegou a ver se os dados que você passa via POST estão sendo passados e recebidos corretamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que está recebendo essas variáveis do form:

```
$servico = $_POST['servico'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
```

Coloque assim nessa linha:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE servico LIKE '%".$servico."%' ORDER BY servico ASC";`

Em vista está faltando o "%"

No form você seta 2x a cidade, mesmo no input de servicos:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">Serviço:</i></span>
<select name="cidade" id="cidade" class="form-control">
```

Correto:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">Serviço:</i></span>
<select name="servico" id="servico" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Arrumei, mas ainda printa a tabela inteira sem filtrar. :/

Comment: Faz o seguinte, dá um `echo $sql` antes de ser executado, e veja como ele está trazendo a query montada. Se estiver correta, testa no seu banco direto para ver se está trazendo o que você quer.

Comment: Então, eu tinha cometido um erro, dá uma olhadinha na edição.

Comment: De onde está trazendo esses valores de $_POST ? Esse select em cima delas que não são correto !?

Comment: Tem um formulário de filtro em uma página e quando clica no submit ele redireciona pra uma outra página onde deveria aparecer a tabela já filtrada. Esse formulário da primeira página é POST

Comment: Certo. Fez o teste para ver o que está trazendo o select ? Onde fez `//echo($sqli);` Deixe `echo ($sqli); die();`

Comment: O select do $sql tá normal, nenhum problema com ele. Mas depois do select do $sqli nada aparece. O problema é com ele.

Comment: Comenta essa linha `if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico))` veja o que está trazendo o select, pode ser que esse if seu está dando erro.

Comment: Comentei o if e dei um echo no $sqli. Me apredentou: `
SELECT * FROM teste WHERE servico LIKE '%%' ORDER BY servico ASC`, vê que o "servico" que deveria aparecer entre os %% não aparece.

Comment: Seu `$_POST['servico'];` está com problema, não está chegando

Comment: Sim, mas eu coloquei no formulário method POST.

Comment: Aí seria outro problema @MarianaFerreira. O seu input tem que ter o nome correto, você puxar da forma correta, etc Abre outro tópico e posta seu código do form para ajudarmos.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67873/discussion-between-mariana-ferreira-and-raoni-bz).

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se a `query` está OK. E tente ao invés disto:

```
if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico)) 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE servico LIKE '".$servico."' ORDER BY servico ASC";
```

Utilizar isso (*Como não compartilhou a tabela tratei tudo como varchar):

```
    $conditions = "WHERE ";
if($servico){
    $conditions .=  "servico like '%$servico%'";         
}

if($estado){
    if($conditions == "WHERE ") {
        $conditions .=  "estado like '%$estado%'";
    }else{
        $conditions .=  "and estado like '%$estado%'";
    }
}
if($cidade){
    if($conditions == "WHERE ") {
        $conditions .=  "cidade like '%$cidade%'";
    }else{
        $conditions .=  "and cidade like '%$cidade%'";
    }
}
if($conditions == "WHERE "){ $conditions .= " 1 = 1 ";}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM teste '.conditions.' ORDER BY servico, estado, cidade ASC';
```

Comment: Obrigada por responder! Enfim, é tudo varchar mesmo, tentei usar seu código mas continua printando a tabela inteira sem filtrar.

Comment: Printa a consulta antes de enviar para o mysqli. coloca depois desse trexo um `echo $sql;`

Comment: Então, eu tinha cometido um erro, dá uma olhadinha na edição.